How to load a pointer to a function defined in a different compilation unit in Assembly language?
I need to load an effective address of a function defined in a different compilation unit, so that I can call it via a pointer. I am facing challenges in accomplishing that task in an Assembly language. Below is a minimal example to reproduce the issue.
Compilation unit 1 is called callee.s and has the following source code:
.section .text

.globl myfunc
.type myfunc, @function

myfunc:

    movq $0, %rax
    ret

Compilation unit 2 is called caller.s and has the following source code:
.section .text

.globl mymain
.type mymain, @function

mymain:

    leaq myfunc, %rdi

    movq $0, %rax
    ret


I am trying to compile the source code into a shared library like this:
$ g++ -m64 -Wall -Werror -Og -fPIC -shared -o libfunc.so callee.s caller.s

That however does not work, and throws the following compilation error:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccHfkA7c.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `myfunc' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

What is the best way to solve the issue and make leaq work as expected?

Side note: -Wall -Werror -Og -fPIC are only meaningful to the C/C++/... compiler.  They have no effect when processing assembly language.

You'll need movq myfunc@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdi in a shared object (PIC).  In a PIE executable, instead use leaq myfunc(%rip), %rdi.

Added a duplicate that explains how the mechanism works.

You can also use lea myfunc(%rip), %rdi in a shared library if the symbol is "hidden" (not exported to be called from outside the shared library).  The default is "global", in which case the linker stops you from getting the address directly; you have to go through the GOT.

Thank you very much for all your answers. movq myfunc@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdi did the trick! Also thank you for sharing the links to an interesting read about GOT. Much appreciated!
